# Various JS reload page instructions failing if not preceeded by console.log()

Tags: javascript, delay, reload, console.log, history

Just wanted to report possible JS bug: I tried various reload page instructions but they all fail most times. However, the problem seems "resolved" by adding a console.log() line before. Is this a normal JS behaviour? My problematic code chunk is the following:

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                let fields = [verifyPassword, updateText];
                if (fields.some(field=>(field.value === '' || field.value === null || field.value === NaN))){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Fill in the form!');
                } else {
                    console.log("Now this page should reload..."); // if this line is removed, reload functions work rarely
                    document.location.reload(true); // same happens with history.go(0) etc.
                };
            });
```

Comment: Can you write a live example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/)?

Comment: My guess would be this: The default  behaviour of a form after submitting is routing you to the response that the server will send after handling the form. So you basically have a race condition of you reloading the form page manually, or the server response redirecting you to the forms result. So when you add a console.log, you force the browser to do additional JS work, making your own reload more likely to trigger. So either event.preventDefault() every time and do the routing manually, or have the form response coming from the server reroute you back to the form page, not a mix of the two.

Comment: @Shilly
thanks. The post request's route has indeed a res.redirect("back"), while the form's action instead routes to a page unreachable by the user, which serves only as the form's destination. Is this incorrect in your opinion?